# Placing 2 for loops inside a findstr inside another for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can one place 2 for loops inside a findstr inside a for loop?

What I have is two for loops inside a findstr inside a for loop. Am I doing the parentheses correctly?

I am wanting to find var1 (%%A) inside *.map files, which will be at the end of a line. If found I want to grab the second item (%%B) on that line and call it var2 and the fourth item (%%C) on that line and call it var3. Then echo all three variables.

```
@echo off


SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /f "delims=" %%A in (Marks.txt) do (

set var1=!var1!%%A


findstr /e "!var1!" "*.map"

if not errorlevel 1 (

for /f "tokens=2" delims=%=%,." %%B do (
set var2=!var2!%%B
)

&

for /f "tokens=4" delims=%=%,." %%C do (
set var3=!var3!%%C
)

)

)



echo !var1!
echo !var2!
echo !var3!

choice /C X /T 8 /D X > nul
```

I'm getting an error and the window closes so I can't read it. I try using a timer and a pause but I can't keep the cmd prompt open.

Comment: Read up on the `for` loops.  You have some extra `"`, and no `in` specified.

Comment: To troubleshoot, don't double-click your .bat file (because then it will close the window if there's an error, as you're seeing).  Instead open a command prompt and run the batch file from there.

Comment: ahhh, I see it now. Ill post back if I have further issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my issues. I had extra quotation marks and was missing the in (....) part.